# Python list permutations in lexicographic order

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is about [Lexicographic Ordering algorithms](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-explain-an-algorithm-that-generates-permutations-using-lexicographic-ordering) and its works but how can i change the style of the code to **professional** coding style?

```
from typing import List    



def swap(_list: List, index1: int, index2: int):
        _list[index1], _list[index2] = _list[index2], _list[index1]
        return _list
    

def lexico_graphic(items: List):
    paths = [items]
    while True:
        # step 1
        largest_i = None
        for i in range(len(items) - 1):
            if items[i] < items[i + 1]:
                largest_i = i
        if largest_i is None:
            return paths

        # step 2
        largest_j = 0
        for j in range(len(items)):
            if items[largest_i] < items[j]:
                largest_j = j

        # step 3
        items = swap(items, largest_i, largest_j)

        # step 4
        items = items[:largest_i + 1] + items[:largest_i:-1]
        paths.append(items)
```

thanks for your time

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: For me, the token ‘items: List’ causes compile-time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python objects are passed into functions by creating a [reference that points to the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140747/16763958), meaning that when you invoke your function `swap()` on list `items`, local `_list` refers to the exact same `items` object you passed in there. When you mutate `_list` in the next line (`_list[index1], _list[index2] = _list[index2], _list[index1]`) the underlying object changes, which means your function is no longer [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function): **you were trying to return a new list with 2 items swapped, but instead modified the original list**.

If you don't want this function to mutate the original list you can write it like this:

```
def swap(_list: List, index1: int, index2: int):
    new_list = _list[:]  # equivalent to `_list.copy()`
    new_list[index1], new_list[index2] = new_list[index2], new_list[index1]
    return new_list
```

As you can see the original list never changes.

If you instead wanted the function to mutate your list, you can get rid of the `return` statement:

```
def swap(_list: List, index1: int, index2: int):
    _list[index1], _list[index2] = _list[index2], _list[index1]
```

and use it without the assignment:

```
swap(items, largest_i, largest_j)

# instead of

items = swap(items, largest_i, largest_j)
```

---

The algorithm looks fine, but naming may need some adjustments:
`_list` - underscores in python are used as [access modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers), this parameter can be named `items` for example
`lexico_graphic` - it's unclear what this function does by looking at its name